# /etc/network/interfaces not changing server IP

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, static-ip

My interfaces file which used to govern the IP configuration of my Ubuntu server is no longer having any affect over the interface settings on my ethernet int. On an identical hardware machine I have:

```
auto lo eth0
iface eth0 inet static
       address 192.168.0.51
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 192.168.0.1
       dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

On a newly installed 16.04.3 Ubuntu Server I have:

```
auto lo enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet static
       address 192.168.0.59
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 192.168.0.1
       dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Regardless of whether I `ifdown` and then `ifup` or flush the interface or even reboot the machine it won't take the configuration. On another  machine with identical hardware, I installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 Desktop and was able to configure it from the GUI but not from the CLI using the same method I tried above. **Can someone please hint at my error?**

The `ifconfig` output on the first quote says `eth0`, the `ifconfig` output of the second device says `enp0s25` for it's interface that it why I specified them as such. The desktop Ubuntu that had the same problem had the same `ifconfig` output of `enp0s25`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NetworkManager service controls just about everything related to networking on most modern Linux systems UNLESS you disable it. There is a "TUI" that you can use to set the network settings on specific connections using "nmtui". (NetworkManager Text User Interface).

From the command line just type "sudo nmtui" and it will launch the interface. It may ask you to install it if it is not installed. After making the changes to your connection, exit the program and type "systemctl restart NetworkManager". If that doesn't work then try "systemctl stop NetworkManager" and edit the file /etc/network/interfaces the same way that you did with the nmtui. Finally reboot with NetworkManager still "stopped" and you should see the changes take effect when you type ifconfig on your next reboot.

Of course, all of what I just said does not apply if you have disabled NetworkManager. With NetworkManager disabled you should be able to edit the ifcfg networking scripts to edit the connection. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: be sure to run nmtui and select enp0s25. Make your edits to this connection/interface, and then run the systemctl command.

Comment: Try to completely disable NetworkManager, and then try editing the network interface using the command line (original way you were trying)

Comment: Alright a bit of caps lock fury, a tuna sandwich and several reboots later and we have ourselves a winner.